# How to Retrieve Random Girl or Boys ID in facebook app

Tags: facebook

Hello I am Coding a small valentine app.

I need to know how to retrieve a random girl's ID if a boy is using the app and vice versa.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to do this would be to just get the user's friends and then filter them yourself by gender/sex. After this the task becomes "Select a random array element". :) You should of course buffer the user's friends somewhere if you plan on repeating that multiple times.